# Clean Install Win10 After Upgrading Win7 to Win8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I bought a *full* boxed Win7 Ultimate copy *years* ago at a retail store.  A few years later, I used a $40 promo offer to upgrade to Windows 8 for a discounted price via Arvato digital services, LLC. Later, I upgraded the same PC to Windows 8.1 for *free*. Now, I want to do the *free* upgrade to Windows 10, but the upgrade assistant is telling me that I don't have compatible hardware.  I *know* that's a bunch of bologna because I have tested preview builds of Win10 on that very same hardware.  For this reason and others, I want to do a *clean* install of Win10 onto the said PC.

I think the *present* Microsoft documentation says:
"If you haven’t upgraded to Windows 10 yet and perform a clean installation, you’ll need to enter a qualifying product key for Windows 7, Windows 8.1 or Windows 10..."
  I'm thinking I have license keys for *both* Windows 7 Ultimate (Full) and Windows 8 (Upgrade), but I'm not sure which one to use.  On the one hand, I'm wondering if it is okay to *clean* upgrade to Windows 10 using a Win8 (Upgrade) key.  On the other, I'm wondering if I somehow invalidated my Windows 7 (Full) key when I upgraded to Win 8.

If I want to reformat my HD and do a *clean* upgrade to Windows 10, should I use my Windows 7 license key or my Windows 8 license key?

Comment: Why don't you just try both?  If the upgrade assistant is telling you your hardware isn't compatible it likely isn't

Comment: I don't think the hardware compatibility argument is valid as I'm pretty sure most Windows Vista drivers work fine in Windows 10 assuming you choose the correct 32bit/64bit version...

Comment: Vista hardware drivers do not work on Windows 10.....

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is an upgrade key and will likely not work.

You should use your Windows 7 key. Alternatively you can try to force the update using the tool, which you can download here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I think I understand the rational behind using the Windows 7 key, but I *thought* I read somewhere in a EULA once that upgrading windows would cause you to lose rights to the previous version of windows...

Comment: You cannot use both licenses at the same time, which is what the EULA is referring to.